# Using stream to get results per column in 2D array

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I'm a complete newbie to API stream, and I want to do some operation on a 2D array

The following code is a simplified version of what I want to do.

I have an array of values :

```
int values[][] = new int[][] {{1,2},{3,4},{5,6}};
```

I'd like to process values per column and get

```
int result[] = {x,y}
```

For example, if I do a sum, it should get me

```
result[] = {9, 12}
```

Thanks by advance for your help

Comment: please show us what you tried so we can help adjust your code to a working example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.

```java
      int values[][] = new int[][] { { 1, 2
            }, { 3, 4
            }, { 5, 6
            }
      };
      int[] v = Arrays.stream(values).reduce(new int[] { 0, 0
      }, (a, b) ->
      {
         a[0] += b[0];
         a[1] += b[1];
         return a;
      });
      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(v));
```

EDIT:

In regards to your other question about accomodating different number of columns.  Yes you can do it.  But just because you can doesn't mean you should or that it's the best way.  What follows is a simple method that sums up integers in any 2D array regardless of row length.  It even handles ragged arrays.  Note that this sums up the columns, first come, first served basis as they are treated as though they are left justified relative to each other.

Initialize a irregular (ragged or different row length) array

```java
      int values[][] = new int[][] { { 1
            }, { 20, 3
            }, { 1, 2, 4
            }, { 3, 4, 10
            }, { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
            }
      };
```

Now compute the sum using the following method.

```java
   public static int[] sumColumns(int[][] vals) {
      // compute the maximum row length (most columns)
      int maxColumns = 0;
      for (int r = 0; r < vals.length; r++) {
         maxColumns = Math.max(maxColumns, vals[r].length);
      }

      // use that to initialize the return array
      int[] sums = new int[maxColumns];

      //now just iterate over the rows and columns
      // calculating the sum.  
      for (int r = 0; r < vals.length; r++) {
         for (int c = 0; c < vals[r].length; c++) {
            sums[c] += vals[r][c];
         }
      }
      return sums;
   }
```

To do any rectangular matrix with streams, do the following:

```java
           int[] result2 =
               Arrays.stream(values).reduce(new int[values[0].length], (a, b) ->
            {
               for (int i = 0; i < values[0].length; ++i) {
                  a[i] += b[i];
               }
               return a;
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

My question was not precise enough (sorry for my poor english level).

In the first example with stream it was based on fact that there was 2 values per rows. In my cas I will always have the same numbers of column but I don't know how many at coding time.

So with a variable "size", how code will be modified ?

```
int values[][] = new int[][] {
            {1,2,3},
            {4,5,6},
            {7,8,9}
    };

    int size = 3;
    int[] result2 = Arrays.stream(arr)
            .reduce(new int[size],
                    (a, b) -> new int[] { a[0] + b[0], a[1] + b[1] });
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result2));
```

I'm much more focus on the "a[0] + b[0]" part of code

EDIT : I finally got something, but I though I could do without the for-loop :

```
int values[][] = new int[][] {
            {1,2,3},
            {4,5,6},
            {7,8,9}
    };

    int size = 3;
    int[] result2 = Arrays.stream(values)
            .reduce(new int[size],
                    (a, b) -> {
                    int[] myInt = new int[size];
                    for (int i =0; i < size ; ++i) {
                        myInt[i] = a[i] + b[i];
                    }
                    return myInt;
            });
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result2));
```

Comment: Your question was perfectly clear to me.  Lambdas and streams are useful tools, but they aren't always appropriate the task at hand.  And you're overly complicating the lambda.  See my final edit of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good use case for [`Collectors.teeing`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#teeing(java.util.stream.Collector,java.util.stream.Collector,java.util.function.BiFunction)), but it is available only from Java 12. Just in case, here is a usage example:

```
int[] res =
    Arrays.stream(values)
        .collect(
            Collectors.teeing(
                Collectors.summingInt(arr -> arr[0]),
                Collectors.summingInt(arr -> arr[1]),
                (a, b) -> new int[] {a, b}));
```